# Enable Automatic Backup OrientDB in Pod startup

Tags: backup, orientdb

I am running orientdb in a kubernetes pod.
image: orientdb:3.0.29

I want to configure it for automatic backup. The option is available at OAutomaticBackup handler in orientdb-server-config.xml file. Where "enabled" parameter needs to set true.

This I tried doing in following ways.
 1. Automatic Backup is possible when I create my own docker image and
    replace the configuration files. -worked.
 2. Editing file by going inside container and stop start server.sh file.

But these ways are a bit lengthy, my question is can I set OAutomaticBackup handler "enabled" parameter to true via passing environment variable?